# How to send mail with third party domains?

Tags: 8, emails

I'm using mailsystem and Swift Mailer. Instead of paying for a professional service or self-hosting, I'd like my site email to be sent using my hotmail or another domain I control.

Eg let's say my Drupal domain is **mydomain.com**. I want the site mail address to be **somethingelse@hotmail.com** or **me@somethingelse.com**

Is this possible and does it need special configuration?

All my attempts to send mail using Outlook's STMP server or myother domain's SMTP service have led to refused connections.

Comment: Since spammers were using tactics like this one, all mail providers have blocked most third party deliveries. So `somethingelse@hotmail.com` is out of the question. However, @domain.com **is allowed only if** you add both SPF and DKIM records that effectively say, “allow the server with the IP address of xx.xx.xx.xx to send emails that appear to originate from @other-domain.com.”

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send email via SMTP using Outlook's SMTP server. Make sure you have set Swiftmailer to send mail via SMTP.

- **SMTP server:** smtp-mail.outlook.com or smtp.office365.com
- **Port:** 587
- **Encryption:** TLS

Use your Hotmail address and password to log in. You'll probably need to enter your Hotmail address under "Configuration" -> "Basic site settings".

Your web hosting provider may block outgoing SMTP ports. Check with their support to make sure.

More information:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-IMAP-and-SMTP-settings-for-Outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/send-emails/smtp-submission-improvements#new-behavior-when-submitting-messages